# Demonstration for method of finding square roots modulo a prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) states [Algorithm 3.39](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf#page=16) for solving $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ (for prime $p\ge5$ and $\left({a\over p}\right)=+1$ ):

> 1. Choose random $b\in\mathbb Z_p$ until $b^2-4a$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$, i.e., $\left({b^2-4a\over p}\right)=-1$ .
> 2. Let $f$ be the polynomial $x^2−bx+a$ in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$ .
> 3. Compute $r=x^{(p+1)/2}\bmod f$ using [Algorithm 2.227](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap2.pdf#page=37) (Note: $r$ will be an integer).
> 4. Return $(r,−r)$ .

How can we prove the correctness of this algorithm?

Note: $\left({a\over p}\right)$ is the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol); one of several ways to compute it is as $a^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p$ with result $p-1$ replaced by $-1$.

Note: [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52273/555) is context and a worked-out example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the condition on $b^2-4a$, $f$ is irreducible. Therefore $R=\Bbb Z_p[x]/(f(x))$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{p^2}$, the finite field of order $p^2$. Write $\xi$ for the image of $x$ in $R$. Over $R$ we have
$f(x)=(x-\xi)(x-\xi^p)$ so that
$\xi^{p+1}=a$ in $R$. Therefore $\xi^{(p+1)/2}$ is a square root in $R$ of $a$. If $a$ is a quadratic residue, then $\xi^{(p+1)/2}\in\Bbb Z_p\subset R$.